# Anyway to send prometheus histogram metrics to cloud watch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am using the CloudWatch agent to send gitlab-runner metrics to CloudWatch.

But for histogram metrics, I get messages like this:

```
023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [1/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_api_request_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [2/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_api_request_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [3/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_api_request_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [4/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_creation_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [5/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_creation_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [6/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_creation_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [7/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_failed_creation_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [8/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_failed_creation_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [9/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_failed_creation_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [10/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_removal_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [11/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_removal_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [12/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_removal_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [13/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_stopping_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [14/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_stopping_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [15/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_stopping_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [16/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_job_duration_seconds_bucket with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [17/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_job_duration_seconds_sum with type: histogram
2023-10-05T12:10:50Z D! [18/1000] Unsupported Prometheus metric: gitlab_runner_job_duration_seconds_count with type: histogram
```

And the metrics also don't appear in cloudwatch.

Still, some of them would be extremely helpful!

**Is there any way I can get some information from this still in cloudwatch?**

i.E. could I rename the metrics, so that I have:

```
gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_creation_duration_seconds_bucket_one
gitlab_runner_autoscaling_machine_creation_duration_seconds_bucket_two
...
```

as metrics and build my dashboards/alarms from this?

I tried around with CloudWatch agent, but I have not found